# Aumentar numero con jquery y localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, local-storage

Estoy usando `localstorage` y `getTime`, para recibir la hora y guardarla en `localstorage` y luego calcular si ha pasado `1 minuto` y actualizar el `localstorage` y mostrar un texto en un `div`.  (aclaro que esto es fake, por ello el Math random y localstorage)

El problema que tengo es que al actualizar la pagina no mantiene el texto, quiero que se mantenga el texto y que cuando pasen los 60 segundos simplemente se actualice ( en este caso cuando la persona re-cargue la pagina) se vean los cambios.

```
function hasOneDayPassed(){
  var lastclear = localStorage.getItem('lastclear'),
      time_now  = (new Date()).getTime();
  // .getTime() returns milliseconds so 1000 * 60 = 60 sec
  if ((time_now - lastclear) > 1000 * 60) {
        localStorage.clear();
        localStorage.setItem('lastclear', time_now);
        $('#now-people').text( Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + ' people are looking right now');   
  }
}

hasOneDayPassed(); // run the code
```

Comment: No puedes usar `localstorage` para saber cuantas personas diferentes estan viendo actualmente tu página ya que `localstorage` es un `Storage` del navegador, es decir, que los valores almacenados son por persona y no se comparten.

Comment: para cumplir con tu objetivo, lo que haria seria ir guardando en una bd la cantidad de usuarios se loguearon

Comment: Esto es algo Fake! no es real, por eso el Math Random XD

Answer (score 1):

He actualizado mi codigo, para que guarde el numero de personas y el tiempo, cuando se evalue el tiempo que ha pasado, se asigna los items en localstorage y para las personas use math random.

```
    function hasOneDayPassed() {
      var lastclear = localStorage.getItem('lastclear'),
        now_p = localStorage.getItem('now_p'),
        time_now = (new Date()).getTime();

      // .getTime() returns milliseconds so 1000 * 60 = 1 minute
      if ((time_now - lastclear) > 1000 * 60) {
        localStorage.clear();
        localStorage.setItem('lastclear', time_now);
        localStorage.setItem('now_p', Math.floor(Math.random() * 20));
      }
  $('#looking-now').html('<i class="fas fa-user"></i> ' + now_p + ' people are looking right now');
    }
    hasOneDayPassed(); // run the code
```

Comment: ¿Esto es la solución al problema o una edición a la pregunta? No termina de quedar claro

Comment: La solucion, pero no puedo marcar la solucion hasta dentro de 2 dias.

Answer (score 0):

Para actualizar el dato cada minuto puedes utilizar el metodo timeOut.

```js
setTimeout(function(){

 alert("Vamos a actualizar el dato"); 

}, 60000);
```