# ¿cómo puedo aplicar localStorage en mi contador regresivo para que al visitar otra página no empiece el contador de nuevo a contar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin

Tengo este código que va con un plugin de jQuery para crear un cronómetro regresivo pero no se como guardar la variable tiempo para que no me vuelva a contar si salgo de esta página. He leído sobre `localStorage` pero no se como aplicarlo a este código. Alguien me puede ayudar por favor?

```
var time = (new Date().getTime() + 30000);

$(function () 
   {$('#reloj').countdown(time)
    .on('update.countdown', function (event) {
      var format = '%M:%S';
      $(this).html(event.strftime(format)); })
    .on('finish.countdown', function (event) {
      $(this).html('This offer has expired!')
        .parent().addClass('disabled');
    });

});
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Aumentar numero con jquery y localstorage](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/129411/aumentar-numero-con-jquery-y-localstorage)

Answer (score 2):

Deberías setear con `localStorage.setItem('nombreVariable', 'valor')` y obtener el valor con `localStorage.nombreVariable`, entonces podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
// si no existe la variable, la creo
if (localStorage.time === undefined) {
  localStorage.setItem('time', new Date().getTime() + 30000);
}

$(function () 
   // utilizo la variable del storage
   {$('#reloj').countdown(localStorage.time)
    .on('update.countdown', function (event) {
      var format = '%M:%S';
      $(this).html(event.strftime(format)); })
    .on('finish.countdown', function (event) {
      $(this).html('This offer has expired!')
        .parent().addClass('disabled');
    });

});
```

Comment: Genial!!! funciona, muchas gracias Kleith

Comment: Si te pareció correcta, no olvides de marcar como correcta la respuesta.